# AngularJS Filter for ng-repeat, how to get access to the filtered data

Tags: angularjs

I have tried to make the title as descriptive as possible.
I have a set of data which I use **ng-repeat** to display in a table. There is also a filter applied so the user can type in a search bar and it will filter the results of the **ng-repeat**, there is nothing special about the filter (it is the default **filter**.
This obviously filters the data and shows it correctly.
The issue is, I also have a dropdown allowing the user to specify what sort of report they want.

The tablature data is **raw**, but they can select **bar** or **line** and it will show a graph. The data for the graph is created when they load the page. It takes the **raw** data and transforms it into **labels** and **series**.

What I would like to happen, is that when a filter is applied, the function transforms the filtered data, but I have no idea how I can actually get access to that data.
Does anyone know how I might go about it?

---

## Update

I tried adding the **filter** to the controller and then doing my conversion in that function like this:

```
// Apply our filter
self.applyFilter = function () {
    var filteredList = $filter('filter')(self.list, self.filter);
    self.list = filteredList;
    self.chartData = provider.getOverdueData(filteredList);
};
```

The problem with that, is that it is invoked many times and causes a **$rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the error was caused by the new array which was being created each time **applyFilter** was invoked. I am not sure why an actual filter works (i.e. in the view) rather than in the function because they are doing the same thing ?!
But I was able to get around this issue by using **angular.equals**. First when I get the data, I had to store the result into a separate array, then when I invoke my **filter** I can use the unmodified array.

```
// Get our report
provider.overdueCollections().then(function (response) {
    self.models = response;
    self.list = response;
    self.predicate = 'center';
    self.chartData = provider.getOverdueData(response);
});
```

Once that was done, the table used **self.list** as it's datasource, but the **applyFilter** used the **self.models** to apply the filter to. It now looks like this:

```
// Apply our filter
self.applyFilter = function () {

    // Create our filtered list
    var filteredList = $filter('filter')(self.models, self.filter);

    // Check to see if we are the same as the current list
    var isSame = angular.equals(self.list, filteredList)

    // If we are not the same
    if (!isSame) {

        // Update our scope
        self.list = filteredList;
        self.chartData = provider.getOverdueData(filteredList);
    }
};
```

This meant that the data was only applied to the scope if it changed.